# Amazon SES - Can't get email to be delivered

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-ec2

I have an aws ubuntu server running a node.js application. I am trying to build a simple forgot password feature which sends users email. The code runs but no email is delivered, so I assume I am still missing something.

1) Within SES I verified the email domain a2zcribbage.com. I assume this means I can now send email from any alias under this domain, right?

2) I npm installed the SES module onto my ec2 server.

3) My code looks as follows:

```
aws.config.update({accessKeyId: 'MYKEY', secretAccessKey: 'MYKEY', region: 'us-west-2'});
var ses = new aws.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}); // load AWS SES
var to = [post.email]; // send to list
var from = 'support@a2zCribbage.com'; // this must relate to a verified SES account
ses.sendEmail( { // this sends the email @todo - add HTML version
      Source: from, 
      Destination: { ToAddresses: to },
      Message: {
        Subject: { Data: 'a2zCribbage - Temporary Password' },
        Body: {
          Text: {
            Data: "Your username is: " + userName + ". Your temporary password is: " + tempPassword
          }
        }
      }
    }, function(err, data) { if (err) console.log(err); });
```

The code runs without error, but no email is delivered. How do I debug this further given there's no error?

Comment: Can you console.log(data) so we can see what is returned?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for your issue:

1. Make sure you have been removed from sandbox, to do that, you need contact aws to extend the limits, that's free service for any aws accounts.
2. register a real mailbox directly to SES, for example, `support@a2zCribbage.com` to test if the code works or not.
3. From the code, seems you missed to load aws sdk.

   var aws = require('aws-sdk');
4. create a SNS task, subscript a SMS or mailbox, enable bounced or complain notification in SES, with it, you can confirm if the setting is proper or not.

let me know if this can help you to fix your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "register a real mailbox directly to SES". There is no actual mailbox support@a2zCribbage.com. If I need to register  a mailbox, what's the point of the "verify domain" option in SES vs. the "verify email address"?

Comment: My account is only running in the sandbox. To send email to an actual user I need to submit to have it moved out of the sandbox, right? If so, that's at least one reason it's failing.

Comment: @PaulGregson The reason I ask to register a real mailbox (if you don't have in that domain, register a gmail) to test if the nodejs code is correct or not. I can't see your aws console, so we don't know if you submit domain in SES properly.

Comment: For your second comment, I don't understand what you are talking. where is the sandbox, a EC2 instance or your local pc?

Comment: On the SES console, under "Email Sending", it says "Your Amazon SES account has "sandbox" access in region US West (Oregon). With sandbox access you can only send email to the Amazon SES mailbox simulator and to email addresses or domains that you have verified. To be moved out of the sandbox, please request a sending limit increase. " So when I tried an email address I just verified it works, so I just need to be moved out of the sandbox to be able to send to everyone I think.

Comment: so you need :  To be moved out of the sandbox, please request a sending limit increase.  That means you need contact aws to extend the limit, that's free service for any aws accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question here. Good feedback from everyone. The one thing I was missing is that by default, when you create an SES account, you are put into a "sandbox" mode, and not a full fledged email sending mode, so I was trying to send emails and it wasn't allowing it. Once I requested I be taken out of sandbox mode everything worked just fine.